# Control TCP header fields from a user program

Tags: c, networking, linux-kernel

Is it possible to set the fields of a TCP header from a user program?  The man page for tcp(7) does not list any fields which can be controlled using setsockopt(2). For IP, we can control the MTU, TTL fields using the setsockopt(2).

```
int sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

/* set the TCP fields now */
...
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use raw sockets to set the  TCP/UDP headers from a user program

> int fd = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);

More info on the link http://csis.bits-pilani.ac.in/faculty/dk_tyagi/Study_stuffs/raw.html

Search for RAW sockets and you will find more

One more good reference is the Unix network programming by Richard stevenson